# Best way of organising code with multiple "socket.on" calls

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, sockets, socket.io

I have a program which uses nodejs and socket.io to conduct a live quiz game with multiple players.

My issue is that I have a lot of **socket.on()** calls in my *app.js*(my server code), making the file very long as they need to be inside  **io.on('connection', function(){})** to work.

I would like to know what the best way of organising/splitting them up would be. Here's a visual representation of what the code looks like:

```
io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    socket.on('Add Room', function () {...
    })

    socket.on('Joined Lobby', function () {...
    })

    socket.on('Request Game Start', function () {...
    })

    socket.on('Answered Question', function () {...
    })
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Bundle related callbacks into config functions and place each in a separate file like so:

```js
// configRoomCbks.js

export function configRoomCbks (socket) {
    socket.on('Add Room', function () {...
    })

    socket.on('Joined Lobby', function () {...
    })

    socket.on('Request Game Start', function () {...
    })
}
```

```js
import { configRoomCbks } from "./configRoomCbks"

io.on('connection', function (socket) {
    configRoomCbks(socket);

    // more callback config functions here
    // e.g. configGamePlayCbks(socket)
}
```

Comment: This makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks, I'll try doing this!

Comment: Using exports the way you have is equivalent to using ```module.exports = configRoomCbks;``` I assume.

Comment: Np! Example is equivalent to `module.exports.configRoomCbks = function () {}` and in the main file `const configRoomCbks = require("./configRoomCbks").configRoomCbks;` but you can change your exports so that the function is the default export if you want.